# Converting AssertNotSame to AssertThat

Tags: junit, assert

I'm looking to have more intuitive assert on my automated tests. I have one assert to verify if a error message is showing up, that is giving a little bit of headache.

```
Assert.assertNotSame((ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.className("notification-title"), "Error message")), "Error message");
```

Any suggestion on how I can convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being more simple than I thought:

`assertThat((ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.className("notification-title"), "Error message")), is(not("Error message")));`

The notSame and False was confusing me :D